# Why doesn't this CSS selector work (selecting sub-menu in Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming

I am trying to select the sub-menu item from a Wordpress default sidebar menu, and I am trying to write a CSS selector for that. I thought I understand CSS selectors, but I don't know what is happening in this case.

The following ones are working:

```
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item .sub-menu { background: red; }
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item li { background: red; }
```

While this one doesn't work:

```
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item li .sub-menu { background: red; }
```

Can someone explain to me **why can I not specify things to be more precise with both specifying class and type here?**

Luckily at this level of customization I don't need to select things more precisely (I only want to hide sub-menu items), but can someone tell me **how to make the non-working example work?**

Here is a [live site](http://kek.org.hu/kozossegikertek/kozossegi-kertek-szervezese/), but it’s the same on all Wordpress installs with TwentyTen theme and a multi-level menu on the left.

**UPDATE**: I think I got a big misunderstanding about the usage of spaces in CSS, so I asked a question here: [usage of spaces in CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851927/specifying-css-selectors)

BTW, after understanding the answers and realising what was wrong with my problem, the correct answer for my problem is:

```
.widget_nav_menu li.menu-item ul.sub-menu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item .sub-menu li { background: red; }
```

because `sub-menu` class belongs to `ul` and there is no `sub-menu` class after `li`

Comment: Thanks it works. But do I understand it right that if there is something like <ul class="sub-menu"> then I have to use **either** ul or .sub-menu in CSS, not both?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this:

```
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item li.sub-menu { background: red; }
```

Comment: this shouldn't work, because `sub-menu` class belongs to `ul` and there is no `li` with `sub-menu` class

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.widget_nav_menu ul .menu-item .sub-menu li { background: red; }
```

Because the li item is below the .sub-menu ul...

Comment: Amazing, almost every word is the same as harakiri's answer.

Comment: I know, when I finished writing my answer (2 minutes after him), I saw he had the same answer ! :-S