# usage of spaces in CSS files

Tags: html, css

This one has to be the most basic question but it's not clear in my mind, so I'd like to ask it:

Say you have some basic HTML like this:

```
<div class="a">
    <p class="b">something</p>
    <img class="b">
    <p class="c">something</p>
</div>
```

**How can you select the first `<p>` element using CSS?**

The reason why I'm puzzled that up till now I believed that CSS can work by both specifying type and class, but it seems I cannot do it. So I can have something like: `div p` or `div .b` or `.a p` or `.a .b`but not `div .a p .b` as I was believing and as how every browser tool names the elements (like `div.a p.b`)

**Is all this issue because of the space between the class and the type?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is all this issue because of the space between the class and the type?

Yes, a space is a [descendent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

`a.b` means "An element of type `a` and class `b`".

`a .b` means `a *.b` means "An element of any type and class `b` that is a descendent of an element of type `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.a .b { color:red; }
```

Or even this (though it may not work in older browsers):

```
.a p:first-child { color:red; }
```

If you're going to use the elements name (like `img.className`) you cannot have a space in between the element's name and it's class or id name. Spaces are used as delimiters, and act sort of like a directory tree would: `.a .b p { color:red; }` is synonymous with saying *color all paragraph's red that are in .b's which are in .a's*.

Answer (score 1):

These should all work...

```
div :first-child             //first child of a div

p:first-child                //first p

div p:first-child            //first p child of a div

.a p:first-child             //first p child of class .a

div p.b                      //p's with class .b as decedents of div

.a p.b                       //p's with class .b as decedents of class .a
```

No space, as in `p.b` will reference all P with class .b

With a space, as in `p .b` will reference decedents of P with class .b

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, it is because of the space. So selecting the paragraph with class b can be achieved by:

```
.a .b {
/* Rules */
}
```

Or to be more specific:

```
div.a p.b {
    /* Rules */
}
```

Whereas the second rule only selects any p element with the class b which is inside a div with the class a. The first one selects any element with class b inside any element with class a.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
div.a p.b
```

What you are doing with

```
div .a p .b
```

is: fetch the class b elementes, see which one are inside a p, from those which one are inside a element of class a, and of those which one are inside a div.